# How to find string from a list of strings with a specific list of characters?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a given list of string and a list of characters and I want to check the string with containing a specific character. Here is an example:

```
Dictionary = ["Hello", "Hi"]
Character = ['e','i']
```

it must return a "Hello" else empty list

I am comparing a list of characters with a list of strings but it is giving me a type error.

```
Dictionary = ["Hello", "Hi"]
Character = ['e']
emptystring = ""
def findwords(dictionary,character):
   for i in dictionary,character:
      for j in dictionary:
          if character[i] == dictionary[i][j]:
             return dictionary[i]
          else:
             j+=1
    i+=1
return emptystring

k = findwords(Dictionary,Character)
k

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-49-996912330841> in <module>
----> 1 k = findwords(Dictionary,Character)
      2 k

<ipython-input-48-9e9498ec1a51> in findwords(dictionary, character)
      5     for i in dictionary,character:
      6         for j in dictionary:
----> 7             if str(character[i]) == str(dictionary[i][j]):
      8                 return str(dictionary[i])
      9             else:

TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not list
```

Comment: your code seems very complex. You can use `in` (substring match) and `any` probably. But it's not clear what you want to achieve exactly.

Comment: Like in Dictionary the first string "Hello" contains 'e' then it will return "Hello".

Comment: but your example isn't clear enough.Does your program tests if `i` is in `Hello` too? for instance if your list is `['Hello','Hi','Yes`]` what should the program output be?

Comment: if str(character[i]) == str(dictionary[i][j] -> i should be number which is not, it's a list.

Comment: No problem. Thanks for taking interest in my code. I appreciate you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this.

```
Dictionary = ["Hello", "Hi"]
Character = ['e']

def findwords(dictionary,character):
    tmp = ""
    for i in dictionary:
        #convert string to char list
        str_arr = list(i)
        for j in character:
            #if char is in char list then save it in tmp variable
            #if you want multiple values then use array instead of tmp
            if j in str_arr:
                tmp = i
    return tmp

k = findwords(Dictionary,Character)
print(k)
```

Answer (score 0):

This might clean up your code a bit, I think it is what you are going for...

```
Dictionary = ["Hello", "Hi"]
Character = ["e"]


def findwords(dictionary, character):
    for i in dictionary:
        if any(j in i for j in character):
            return i
    return ""
```

For all matches:

```
def findwords(dictionary, character):
    matches = []
    for i in dictionary:
        if any(j in i for j in character):
            matches.append(i)
    if matches:
        return ",".join(matches)
    else:
        return ""
```

It will see if anything in the substring matches your word. If it does, return the word, else `""`

> findwords(["Hello", "Hi"],["e"])
>
> 'Hello'
>
> findwords(["Hello", "Hi"],["k"])
>
> ''

For your issue:

> TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not list

```
   for i in dictionary,character: <-- I will be list ['Hello', 'Hi']
      for j in dictionary:
          if character[i] == dictionary[i][j]:  <---- you can't do character[i] where i is ['Hello', 'Hi']
```

Comment: Thanks for understanding my question and helping me out but what should I do if I am giving a list of characters like ["e", "i", "o"]

Comment: Do you want to output all matches? In a list? I will add it

Comment: Yes, I want it too.

Comment: @TamjeedAnees added, however if you want to not double count words if the list was `Heillo, Hi` you will want to maybe `.pop()` the item off the list (this will require tracking index)

Comment: Thank you. I really appreciate your answer.